# data extraction using camelot

Tags: python, data-extraction, python-camelot

I am encountering ghostscript error : fatal while extracting data from a pdf using camelot in jupyter notebook.

```py
import camelot.io as cam
tables = cam.read_pdf("monotogomry 6th edtn.pdf", pages ='81')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import camelot as cam
tables = cam.read_pdf("monotogomry 6th edtn.pdf", pages ='81')
```

and you can have look into camelots page: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/